# Getting minimum value from double array not working

Tags: java, arrays, double, minimum

I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum values from an array of doubles. The maximum value works fine, however, the minimum value always seems to be zero. What would be the best way to get the minimum value? Please note that I cannot use a for loop in this exercise, but a while loop.

```
public class LoopingFloats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] inputHolder = new double[5];
        int inputCounter = 0;
        double total = 0.0d;
        double average = 0.0d;
        double maximum = 0.0d;
        double minimum = inputHolder[inputCounter];
        double interestRate = 0.20d;
        double interestAmount = 0.0d;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(inputCounter <= 4){
            System.out.println("Enter number " + (inputCounter + 1) + ": ");
            inputHolder[inputCounter] = scnr.nextDouble();

            if(inputHolder[inputCounter] >  maximum){
                maximum = inputHolder[inputCounter];
            }
            if(inputHolder[inputCounter] <  minimum){
                minimum = inputHolder[inputCounter];
            }

            total = total + inputHolder[inputCounter];

            inputCounter += 1;

        }

    }

        average = total / 5;
        interestAmount = total * interestRate;

        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + maximum);
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + minimum);
        System.out.println("Interest for total at 20%: " + interestAmount);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're initializing the minimum with a value of 0.0 (default value for elements of a `double[]` array.

Comment: the following double minimum = inputHolder[inputCounter]; initializes minimum to 0.0 by default. You should assign double minimum = Double.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @akshayapandey Forgot a minus sign there.

Comment: no we wish to assign minimum variable to the max value initially, so when it finds a smaller double values, it can assign it to minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
double minimum = inputHolder[inputCounter];
```

Java initialises new variables, and all elements of a new array, to 0 values. [See here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So by default your `minimum` variable is set to 0 and if your array has values greater than 0, your `minimum` variable won't be updated because 0 is less than all other positive values.

What you'll have to do is set it to a very large value, such as 99999, or you can use `Double.MAX_VALUE` which will give you the maximum value a double can store.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) which includes all of your required information (I would also prefer formatted IO). Like

```
double[] inputHolder = new double[5];
double interestRate = 0.20;
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    System.out.printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
    inputHolder[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
    i++;
}
DoubleSummaryStatistics dss = Arrays.stream(inputHolder).summaryStatistics();
System.out.printf("Total: %.2f%n", dss.getSum());
System.out.printf("Average: %.2f%n", dss.getAverage());
System.out.printf("Maximum: %.2f%n", dss.getMax());
System.out.printf("Minimum: %.2f%n", dss.getMin());
System.out.printf("Interest for total at 20%%: %.2f%n", dss.getSum() * interestRate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok excepts initialization of variable`minimum`. Initialize it in while loop after the `inputHolder[inputCounter] = scnr.nextDouble();`statement

```
inputHolder[inputCounter] = scnr.nextDouble();
if (inputCounter == 0) minimum = inputHolder[inputCounter];
```

Hope this will solve your problem.